# Go to URL based on selection from dynamic form

Tags: javascript, form-submit

I'm new to Javascript and i'm trying to tweak a piece of code so that goes to a URL after selecting the outcome from a form. The user selects length, then a choice from widths and that selection should go to the correct page.

I can see in my code that the value of each width variable is being sent to 'alert' which is sending the value to the pop out message but I'd like it to go to the URLs that I've named the values.

This might be a super simple solution but having looked at lot of other threads I can't get my head around how to change the code to go to the URLs.

Thanks for any help

```html
<form name="kits">
<select name="length" size="7" onChange="updatewidth(this.selectedIndex)" style="width: 180px">
<option selected>Select Length</option>
<option value="600x600html">600mm</option>
<option value="800">800mm</option>
<option value="1000">1000mm</option>
<option value="1200">1200mm</option>
<option value="2400">2400mm</option>
<option value="3050">3050mm</option>
</select>
 
<select name="width" size="5" style="width: 180px" onClick="alert(this.options[this.options.selectedIndex].value)">
</select>
</form>
 
<script type="text/javascript">
 
var lengthlist=document.kits.length
var widthlist=document.kits.width
 
var width=new Array()
width[0]=""
width[1]=["600mm|600x600html", "900mm|600x900.html", "1200mm|600x1200.html"]
width[2]=["600mm|800x600.html", "900mm|800x900.html", "1200mm|800x1200.html"]
width[3]=["600mm|1000x600.html", "900mm|1000x900.html", "1200mm|1000x1200.html"]
width[4]=["600mm|1200x600.html", "900mm|1200x900.html", "1200mm|1200x1200.html", "1800mm|1200x1800.html", "2400mm|1200x2400.html"]
width[5]=["600mm|2400x600.html", "900mm|2400x900.html", "1200mm|2400x1200.html"]
width[6]=["1200mm|3050x1200.html", "1500mm|3050x1500.html"] 
 
function updatewidth(selectedwidthgroup){
    widthlist.options.length=0
    if (selectedwidthgroup>0){
        for (i=0; i<width[selectedwidthgroup].length; i++)
            widthlist.options[widthlist.options.length]=new Option(width[selectedwidthgroup][i].split("|")[0], width[selectedwidthgroup][i].split("|")[1])
    }
}
 
</script>
```

Comment: Are you thinking of something along the lines of `location.href = this.options[this.options.selectedIndex].value`?  That should work unless I'm missing something.

Comment: you could also try using the html element <a href=""></a> insteed of your select, this will not require any javascript...

Comment: It worked with the location.href. Thanks so much!

Comment: Is it as simple to make it display a IFrame in the page instead?